# Metaprogramming JS function without #eval

Tags: javascript

I've been attempting to dynamically call functions in JS. In my current situation, I'm using `eval` to build and call the correct function name based upon its parents arguments. Here's an example:

In a `Comments` "class":

```
$scope.getComments = function(id) {
  return getApiData(id, "comments");
};

getApiData = function(id, field) {
  eval("BackendApi.get" + (field.capitalize()) + "(" + id + ")");
  // do something else with `field` down here
};
```

`BackendApi` is a simple REST service. The reason I'm trying to dynamically call these functions is because I found myself writing a lot of repetitive code. I've [read](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/) `eval` is generally considered bad practice and it can be associated with poor performance. In the above example, I would attempt to call a function with this syntax:

```
BackendApi.getComments(:id);
```

Note that the `Comments#$scope.getComments` and `BackendApi#getComments` share the same function name for their respective "classes". The biggest problem I'm running into is the `"get" + field` part. Is it possible to call the name of the caller function of `getApiData` instead of `"get"` plus the static field name as an argument? I would appreciate help, and I apologize if I misrepresented any part of JS.

Comment: This is why Angular is great, it brings out the best in the developer.

Comment: `BackendApi['get' + (field.capitalize())](id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array notation to access properties by name:

```
getApiData = function(id, field) {
    return BackendApi['get' + field.capitalize()](id);
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! As a side question, is it possible in JS to get the name of the caller function without passing it through as a parameter to the child function?

Comment: the caller function might not have a name, it could be an anonymous function.

Comment: Maybe you should really be using OO programming, so you can use `this`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but it just feels weird with Angular (this.$scope.getComments).